# Produce a dynamic download from a portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet

Led by this comment in a previous question:

[Portlet: Forward a ResourceRequest to show the full portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843877/portlet-forward-a-resourcerequest-to-show-the-full-portal#comment19043951_5843877)

I was wondering if the best way to generate a dynamic download from a portlet (Like, for example, a dynamically generated PDF or image),  is making a ResourceRequest, or if there is a better alternative approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of ResourceRequests and the serveResource method is to offer a way to serve resources or content fragments. So, yes, using ResourceRequests is a valid way to dynamically create and serve things like PDFs or images.