# Redirecting to render/action methods from serveResource of a portlet

Tags: redirect, render

Am trying to call render method after the `serverResource` method in my `portlet`(`GenericPortlet`). Unfortunately any of my trials does not succeed. I tried `resourceResponse.createRenderURL()`. But the formed seems to be incomplete and my default view is not getting rendered.

I could see `resourceResponse.isCommitted()` method is returning a false in the logger. Even the logger is not getting printed. Am using WebSphere portal v7. Please suggest how do I proceed, Thanks in anticipation.

You can refer to the below site, where they had the same issue, but none of the approaches are working in my scenario.

[How to make the ResourceResponse to forward the request to error page in liferay portlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870593/how-to-make-the-resourceresponse-to-forward-the-request-to-error-page-in-liferay)

Comment: You can redirect to other page using the Java script or the jquery too after you have obtained the response .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved by using the ProcessAction method. Redirection is must in my business scenario. Am able to get the resource in streams if I pass ByteArrayOutputStream instead of response.getPortletOutputStream. And the redirection is also happening based on the conditions in render method.